# VideoView android is not working on android version 4+

Tags: android, android-videoview

Anyone help me. I am preparing application to integrate video into it. Kept video in res/raw folder. Video format .mp4. Working api-level-21. It is working on android devices for android version 2.2 but not on 4+.
Here is my code:
java:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Gift extends ActionBarActivity {

    MediaController mediaController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.gift);
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


        Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sidbday);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        myVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when i click the play button to play video, it appears "Unfortunately, video has stopped".

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown when framework is not ready to play video yet. You can start your video after onPrepared method is called:
instead of `myVideoView.start();` use

```
video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            myVideoView.start();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
I didn't notice that it's an old topic but maybe it hepls someone.

Comment: onPrepared is even not calling. Did any one solve this?